# how can i make a button navigate from scene 1 to scene 2 without displaying both scene content in scene2?

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs5

ive made a button in the scene 1 which i have managed to navigate to scene 2 but when i click the button it goes to scene 2 but displays everthing that is in scene 1 in scene 2, how can sort this out so upon the button click in scene 1 it goes to scene 2 and only display content in scene2.

this is the code im using to navigate from scene1 to 2:

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(10, "Scene 2");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All stage instances created by calling `addChild()` from ActionScript have to be removed by calling `removeChild()`.  Only those instances you place on the stage from the library in the IDE will automatically be removed when you switch scenes.

Try this:

```
function fl_ClickToGoToScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    for ( var i:int = root.numChildren-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        root.removeChildAt(i);
    }

    root.gotoAndPlay(10, "Scene 2");
}
```